# How can I save a date variable without it being overwritten?

Tags: javascript, file, date

I have a conditional that logs the current date the first time it is run.

The second time the conditional is run it overwrites the previous date with the current date and both dates become the current date, however I still want to log the previous date to the file. Is there any way I can save the date when the first condition was run?

The logs show this:

Occurred from Thu Apr 12 2018 08:42:26 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) to **Thu Apr 12 2018 08:42:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time).**

**Occurred from Thu Apr 12 2018 08:42:26 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)** to Thu Apr 12 2018 08:43:31 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time).

I want the second date to become the first date for the next log.

```
switch(message.content)
{
    case ":botOnline":
        dateToggle = new Date();
        fs.appendFile("joinInfo.txt", "Occurred from " + dateToggle + " to " + Date() + " (which is today).\r\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n", (err) =>{
            if (err) throw err;
        });
        break;
}
    /*All variables have been declared and/or initialized at the top of my program.
```

Comment: That works for the first and second time, but what if I want to run the program many more times?

Comment: The logs show this: ------------------------------------------------------

Occurred from Thu Apr 12 2018 08:42:26 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) to Thu Apr 12 2018 08:42:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time).

Occurred from Thu Apr 12 2018 08:42:26 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) to Thu Apr 12 2018 08:43:31 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time).

I want the second date to become the first date for the next log.

Answer (score 0):

Only assign `dateToggle` if it was undefined:

`dateToggle = dateToggle ? dateToggle : new Date();`

Answer (score 0):

Create the date Toggle first time , and store in some service (I kept just window). From next time, check if the value already exists.You can store it in local storage too , if you want it to be available if user closes and opens the window again.

```js
switch(message.content)
{
    case ":botOnline":
        if(!window.dateToggle){
           window.dateToggle = new Date();
          }
        fs.appendFile("joinInfo.txt", "Occurred from " + window.dateToggle + " to " + Date() + " (which is today).\r\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n", (err) =>{
            if (err) throw err;
        });
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code as much as I understand please let me know if you need something else?

```
var isFirstTime = false;
var previosDate;
switch (message.content) {
    case ":botOnline":
        var date = new Date();
        if (isFirstTime) {
            previosDate = date;
        } else {
            date = previosDate;
            previosDate = new Date();
        }

        fs.appendFile("joinInfo.txt", "Occurred from " + date + " to " + previosDate + " (which is today).\r\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n", (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only assign to it for the first time.

```
dateToggle = dateToggle || new Date();
```